# What do Akka's ActorSystem corresponds to, especially in cluster technology?

Tags: java, akka, distributed-computing, distributed, akka-cluster

sorry if I'll be a little noobish here. I'm studying Java Akka and I'm struggling to grasp the exact meaning of an `ActorSystem`. I understand it's like an `Actor` factory, effectively creating the actors I may want to use in my application.

However, I am confused about two things, particularly regarding the **Akka cluster** usage.

- The first is minor: in my application, is the `ActorSystem` unique? I've heard that while it is technically possible to have more than one, usually you only have **one system per JVM**. Is it true? **Would you ever need** to use more than one system in your project?
- The big one: I need to familiarize with the Akka cluster mechanism. When I am distributing my application, what extra **conceptual** meaning do the `ActorSystem` get? Does it correspond to the notion of "node"? Or of "cluster"? For what I got, my machine correspond to a single cluster, which in turn comprises multiple nodes. Is it correct? Where do `ActorSystem`s kick in in this reasoning?

  Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the actors inside the `ActorSystem` are concerned, actors in a different `ActorSystem` may as well be in a different JVM (modulo possible classloader conflicts, etc.).

It's exceptionally rare to need to have multiple `ActorSystem`s in the same JVM: about the only situation where you would strictly need it is a situation like wanting multiple configurations for some functionality in the same JVM (and the functionality being configured isn't flexible about where configuration lives; most/all of Akka's functionality is flexible in this way).  Apart from that, multiple `ActorSystem`s in the same JVM is sometimes useful in tests to save the overhead of multiple JVMs.

So in a cluster, another `ActorSystem` is definitely listening on a different host:port combination.  It's almost certainly running in a different JVM/OS process.  It may or may not be running on a different computer.

An `ActorSystem` will nearly always correspond 1:1 to a cluster node.  It's possible to imagine an implementation that speaks Akka Remoting/Akka Cluster which allows 1 `ActorSystem` to serve as multiple nodes.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! I have still some doubts on your last sentence. Are you saying that 1 `ActorSystem` usually represents 1 node, but it is not a rule (so it may correspond to multiple nodes)? Sorry, I am a bit confused about what a "node" is then. Is it the equivalent of the machine the JVM is running on?

Comment: In Akka Cluster, a node is a host:port:uid combination.  The current implementation uses a set-once uid per `ActorSystem` and identifies as a single host:port (a consequence of this is that if a node leaves the cluster, it's `ActorSystem` cannot rejoin).  However, since any piece of software which follows the protocol can join the cluster, there's nothing really stopping someone from doing an implementation which does something different (e.g. the same `ActorSystem` joining a cluster with different ports, thus joining as 2 nodes).

Comment: So, barring the existence of software that speaks Akka Cluster with some specific internal differences (and I'm not aware of any such software existing, but I'm not aware of any reason it couldn't), in practice a node corresponds to an `ActorSystem`.

Comment: thanks! I'm starting to getting it. One last question, if I may: why would I need to have multiple nodes on the same machine? Freshman guess: in a distributed-system-view, you would only need one node per machine. Software eng guess: you may do so if you want two different, decoupled functionalities and you don't have (or you don't want to use) two machines, so that it makes sense to have two different JVM for them. Did I get it right?

Comment: You don't necessarily ever need to have multiple nodes on the same machine.  However, in the modern world of containers being scheduled (e.g. by Kubernetes) onto machines by something else, the scheduler may put multiple instances of an application on the same machine, so not prohibiting multiple nodes on the same machine allows for recognizing that reality.  This is setting aside the question of: in a world of layers of virtualization, does "same machine" have a universally useful meaning?

Comment: thanks a lot, you've been extremely kind and complete!